# Why doesn't __git_ps1 work in bash anymore on OSX with MacPorts?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, macports

After updating Macports today, I get `-bash: __git_ps1: command not found.`

Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

Macports has updated the old port called `git-core` to just `git`. When updating your ports (`port upgrade outdated`), this will automatically happen.

But: if you used the old `git-prompt.sh` file in your .profile, you will now get the message `-bash: __git_ps1: command not found.`

This is because the path of the file has changed. You should update your .profile to look like this:

```
if [ -f /opt/local/share/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh ]; then                                                                                         
. /opt/local/share/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
fi
```

Comment: Alternatively, symlinking the git-prompt.sh in the folder `/opt/local/share/bash-completion/completions/` should work

Comment: There is also an answer on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871094/2992519)